# Converting a WinJS function definition with a sub-function to TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I've been trying to contribute to excellent [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped) repository of TypeScript.

I encountered an unusual function declaration in WinJS though and wondered what the most succinct TypeScript definition would be for the function, so that the compiler won't complain and Visual Studio Intellisense works correctly.

The method I don't know how to translate to a TypeScript definition/stub is `render.value` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh920315.aspx)):

```
template.render.value(href, dataContext, container)
```

Most functions are easy to translate, but the function on the function, `value`, I don't know how to represent cleanly/correctly.

So far, I've got this for the `Template` class ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229723.aspx)), I just want it to be complete:

```
class Template {
    public element: HTMLElement;
    public extractChild: boolean;
    public processTimeout: number;
    public debugBreakOnRender: boolean;
    public disableOptimizedProcessing: boolean;
    public isDeclarativeControlContainer: boolean;
    public bindingInitializer: any;

    constructor(element: HTMLElement, options?: any);
    public render(dataContext: any, container?: HTMLElement): WinJS.Promise<any>;
    public renderItem(item: any, recycled?: HTMLElement);
    // public render.value(  ***TODO 
}
```

Comment: Here's my quick stab, not knowing anything about WinJS. It doesn't look like render should be a promise. value looks like a promise. render just looks like a property that has a value property that is a promise.

Comment: Also, you can't have a method named "render.value", so you'll have to split them up somehow.

Comment: `render` returns a `Promise` (I'm using it). I understand that functions can't be named that way. It's a function declared on a function in JavaScript. The WinJS library has the function. I didn't create it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I came up with.

```
declare class Template {
    element: HTMLElement;
    extractChild: boolean;
    processTimeout: number;
    debugBreakOnRender: boolean;
    disableOptimizedProcessing: boolean;
    isDeclarativeControlContainer: boolean;
    bindingInitializer: any;

    constructor(element: HTMLElement, options?: any);
    render: {
        (dataContext: any, container?: HTMLElement): WinJS.Promise<HTMLElement>;
        value(href: string, dataContext: any, container?: HTMLElement): WinJS.Promise<HTMLElement>;
    };
    renderItem(item: any, recycled?: HTMLElement);
}
```

My understanding of the WinJS.Promise object returned from `render` is that it's wrapping the HTMLElement passed in as `container` or a new div.  So that's why I typed the promise `WinJS.Promise<HTMLElement>`.

For `render` I just inlined the type rather than giving it a name and declaring it elsewhere because I think that's neater.  The first line inside its definition says what happens when you treat it like a function, and the second is just a regular member of that object.

Comment: That seems to do the trick. I wasn't aware of the syntax for declaring the function on the `render` object directly.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't come up often.